# Differential equation/indefinitely often differentiable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, maxima-minima

I have $y'=f(y)$ and $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$

I want to show, that each solution is indefinitely often differentiable in its existence intervall.

Proof: Because of $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$  each solution is unique and exists. Therefore it holds  $y'=f(y)$ and because of $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$  follows $y \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$
I hope, that's ok.

There is a second question to this: Solution is constant, if it has local max or min.

How can I proof that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you propose in your answer to the first question is circular reasoning, I am afraid: a composition of a $C^1$ and $C^{\infty}$ functions need not be of class $C^{\infty}$.

A proof should proceed by induction.  $t \mapsto y(t)$ is clearly of class $C^1$.  Assume that $t \mapsto y(t)$ is of class $C^k$, so $t \mapsto y'(t) = f(y(t))$ is $C^k$, too, but this means that $t \mapsto y(t)$ is of class $C^{k+1}$.

Regarding your second question, as $f$ is assumed to be $C^{\infty}$, the uniqueness theorem holds.  Let $t_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ be such that a solution $y(\cdot)$ has a local extremum at $t_0$.  Then $y'(t_0) = 0$.  But observe that both $y(\cdot)$ and a function constantly equal to $y_0 := y(t_0)$ are solutions to the initial value problem
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
y' = f(y)
\\
y(t_0) = y_0,
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
so they must be identical.  (Indeed, without uniqueness the property described in your second question holds, too, but a proof is much more tricky.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer:) You say:"But observe that both $y(\cdot)$ and a function constantly equal to $y_0 := y(t_0)$ are solutions to the initial value problem". What do you mean by a function?

Comment: I define a **number** $y_0$ as the value at $t_0$ of the solution $y(\cdot)$ of the equation, and then consider a function taking a constant value $y_0$.

Comment: I see:) You get, that$ y_0 $and$ y$ are solution ot the IVP, but because of the uniqueness must hold $y_0=y $

Comment: But why should $y(t_0)=y_0$ solve $y'=f(y)$. I mean, why should $f(y_0)=0$

Comment: Because $f(y_0) = y'(t_0) = 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much:)